# Vuetify layout with two select or input boxes nicely separated by a hyphen, how do I properly align this?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a simple design that needs to be followed on both larger screens and small mobile screens, which is basically two input/select boxes separated by a hyphen side-by-side. This is a screenshot of the wireframes:

[image]

As simple as that looks, I cannot seem to get the grid system to work for me with that hyphen. It breaks the layout no matter what I do.

I have played around a bit with the different values for cols in screens, but to no avail.

This is what the app I am currently working with looks like (ignore the styling of the select boxes, the important part is their layout in relation to each other and the hyphen separating them):

```js
  new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  template: `
  <div style="{ margin: '20px' }">
    <h2>Without Hyphen</h2>
     <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-select placeholder="Time 1" />
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-select placeholder="Time 2"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <h2>With Hyphen</h2>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-select placeholder="Time 1" />
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        -
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-select placeholder="Time 2"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
   </div>
  `
  })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `shrink` class on the hyphen col, and `no-gutters` on the row (if you want less spacing)..

```
       <v-row no-gutters align="center">
            <v-col auto>
                <v-select placeholder="Time 1" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col class="shrink"> - </v-col>
            <v-col auto>
                <v-select placeholder="Time 2" />
            </v-col>
       </v-row>
```

https://codeply.com/p/wpzUMyrHfX